# change body color dynamically and that should reflect in every page in angular js

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I need to change the color from home page(i.e the landing page after login) which should reflect all the pages.In the home page there will be list of color so that user can choose any color and that should reflect all the pages.

I have created the drop down color in home page and the color is getting changed in that page only now I need to reflect all the pages the same color.
in the below code the user can select a color and it is reflecting the same page but when I move to home1.html page using hyper link I need the sae color also in this page how can I get this.....

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.w3schools.com/lib/w3.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" >
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h4>
        <small>color box</small>
    </h4>
    <select ng-model="color">
        <option value="">--- Select a color ---</option>
        <option value="{{c}}" style="background-color:{{c}}"
                ng-repeat="c in colors">
            {{c}}
        </option>
    </select>
    <p>Selected color: <b style="color:{{color}}">{{color}}</b></p>
    <div style="background-color:{{color}}">

       <div class="square" style="background-color:{{color}}">

<a href="home1.html">Visit our page </a>
</div>

</div>

</div>
</body>
<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.colors = ['Blue', 'Cyan', 'Green', 'Orange', 'Pink', 'Purple', 'Red'];
    $scope.objects = [
        {id: 1, color: 'Blue'},
        {id: 2, color: 'Cyan'},
        {id: 3, color: 'Green'},
        {id: 4, color: 'Orange'},
        {id: 5, color: 'Pink'},
        {id: 6, color: 'Purple'},
        {id: 7, color: 'Red'}
    ];

});



</script>
<style>
p { background-color: LightGray; }

.blue   { background-color: Blue; }
.cyan   { background-color: Cyan; }
.green  { background-color: Green; }
.orange { background-color: Orange; }
.pink   { background-color: Pink; }
.purple { background-color: Purple; }
.red    { background-color: Red; }


.square {
    background: #000;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 10vw;
}
.square h1 {
    color: #fff;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set color variable in `$rootscope.color` which is used as ng-model of your dropdown. Then it will be available to all your states or pages where you could use it.

Comment: instead of using $rootScope use cookies so that if you refresh a page value will not disappear.

Answer (score 1):

- If your app is single-page application, you can set color variable like `$rootscope.color` and access it from other pages.
- With multiple-page application, to store color data from page to other pages, you need something stored in client like cookie, localStorage, etc.